# c structure in shared memory

Tags: c, memory, structure, shared

I have a structure like

```
struct board{
   char name;
   int values[37];
}board
```

Imagine a game where there are several players playing at a single table and they all make different bets on different positions of the values array.The name of the board is unique and a player enters a game specifying the board name. If 2 or more players enter the same board name they all join the same game.

I need to put this structure into shared memory and access/modify the contents of "values"
from different processes at the same time (semaphores are not a problem). I managed to copy the structure in a piece of shared memory but I don't how to access the name to see if a board already exists and things like that.

This is for a school project and I'm a little desperate.... pleeease help and thanks. By the way, the shared memory I want references to the POSIX os

Comment: There is no such thing as "shared memory" in C. If you are referring to any platform specific concept, please specify the platform explicitly (e.g. "this is for my TI-95 calculator").

Comment: First of all, the name is just a single character. It should either be a pointer or an array. And why don't you copy the whole structure into the shared memory? Then you can access it like any other structure. Also, why shared memory? Are each player starting their own program on the computer, or they connecting over some kind of network?

Comment: Doesn't your shm library support named memory regions? If so, you can have each board mapped to a memory region. Either that, or use a red-black tree to track `(name, (struct board *))` pairs.

Also, did you mean `char *name`? (A fixed-size `char` array is better for shm because it's easier to copy and use the pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POSIX shared memory functions are already written with this sort effort in mind:

```
int shm_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode);
```

If you use `"/onica_game_<name>"` for your `*name` parameter, you can easily specify which shared memory segments to attach to for your shared games. (Incidentally, a single `char` is a bit limiting for game names. You might want to use `char name[32];` or something larger to give people an opportunity to name their games something more meaningful.)

I suggest prefixing the name with `onica_game_` because the namespace for POSIX shared memory segments is system-wide.

Comment: thx for the response but that only answern part of my question. after i put the structure in a part of shared memory (using shm_open, truncate, mmap, and memcp for copying the structure), what i end up with is a pointer *ptr to the start of that memory segment. Now how to I put for example 2 into values[16] having only a pointer??? :-<

Comment: @OnicaRadu "having only a pointer"??? pointers are magic, they make all your wishes come true

Comment: @Onica: use `*` to dereference a pointer, ie to access the underlying object type. If `ptr` is a pointer to an object of type `double`, `*ptr` is a double. To access a member of a structure, use the `.` operator. If `t` is an object of type `struct tm`, `t.tm_hour` accesses the member named "tm_hour". Putting pointers (`ptr`) and structs together gives you `(*ptr).member`, or, as an easier way to write the same thing: `ptr->member`.